# Is there an alternative to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database

I'd like a lightweight database for my lightweight RaspPi.  MySQL seems a bit of overkill and involves too much administration.  I'll need one with a perl API.

Comment: Do you think that answers to this question will be completely subjective?

Comment: @Jivings I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do I believe that people will give only opinions and not facts? If others give preferences in their answers, who cares?  As long as they are factual and to the point, I'm interested.

Comment: I'm saying that the answer to this question could be based quite heavily on personal preference. All that means is that we need to keep an closer eye on it to make sure that answers are supported by facts.

Answer (score 25):

You're in luck!  You should try SQLite.  SQLite is very lightweight and implements a large subset of SQL.  Your entire database is stored on a single file.  And there is a perl API.  Here's a link to SQLite's homepage ...

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org)

To install only SQLite ...

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite
```

To install the perl API and SQLite (no need for the above) ...

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-sqlite3-perl
```

You might want to consider DBD::CSV instead (or also) ...

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-csv-perl
```

Comment: I think this answer should list more than just SQLite. There are many solutions.

Comment: Some comments about SQLite limitations when compared to MySQL would also be great.